# I'm getting an undefined method with a form_for when method does exist in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, activemodel

I'm debugging a variable from my controller in a view and it's showing me what I expect to see which is an object with properties:

```
--- !ruby/hash:Parse::Object
alternativeColour: false
collection: 1
colour: 2
favourite: false
gender: 2
image: !ruby/object:Parse::File
  parse_filename: dcefd915-eee7-4203-840b-sdsdsd34refdd-image3.jpg
  url: http://files.parse.com/erre43-7f16-479f-97e6-343434/dcefd-image3.jpg
price: 23.42
productType: 2
recommended: false
size: 6
title: Bomber Jacket
createdAt: '2014-04-03T20:33:41.020Z'
updatedAt: '2014-06-18T19:03:24.220Z'
objectId: yZkfeeNJPm
```

**In my controller I have:**

```
  def edit
      @garment = Parse::Query.new("Garments").eq("objectId", params[:id]).get.first
  end
```

This takes an objectId of an item that was clicked on on another pages and grabs the matching item from parse.com database so I can edit anything I wish to.

Now my edit page loads fine without my form and when I debug the controller var the first piece of code I copied and pasted above it what comes up. So I know for sure I have a returned object.

**I also even tested for a titie by using:**

```
<%= debug @garment["title"] %>
```

This works fine. So now i wish to add my form then make the values of the textfields and select drop downs reflect what's stored in the database for that particular item. The problem is I get an error that states:

```
undefined method `title' for #<Parse::Object:0x007fer0h02y5c0>
```

**Here is my form:**

```
<%= form_for :garment, :url => adminpanel_url, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "formFields", :placeholder => "Title" %> 
  <%= f.text_field :price, :class => "formFields", :placeholder => "Price" %> 
  <%= f.select :recommended, [["Yes", true], ["No", false]], :include_blank => "Make Recommended?" %>
  <%= f.select :alternativeColour, [["Yes", true], ["No", false]], :include_blank => "Alternative Colour?" %>
  <%= f.select :gender, [["Male", 1], ["Female", 2]], :include_blank => "Select Gender" %>
  <%= f.select :productType, [["T-Shirt", 1], ["Shirt", 2], ["Hoody", 3], ["Gilet", 4], ["Jacket", 5]], :include_blank => "Select Product Type" %>
  <%= f.select :size, [["Size 8", 1], ["Size 10", 2], ["Size 12", 3], ["Size 14", 8], ["Small", 4], ["Medium", 5], ["Large", 6], ["X-Large", 7]], :include_blank => "Select Product Size" %>  
  <%= f.select :colour, [["Black", 1], ["Blue", 2], ["Green", 3], ["Grey", 4], ["Navy", 5]], :include_blank => "Select Product Colour" %>
  <%= f.select :collection, [["Tailor Made", 1], ["Raw & Uncut", 2], ["Custom", 3]], :include_blank => "Select Collecton" %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %> 
  <%= f.file_field :image2 %> 
  <%= f.file_field :image3 %> 
  <%= f.file_field :image4 %>
  <%= f.file_field :image5 %>
  <%= f.file_field :image6 %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Item", :id => "addItemButton" %> <br \>
<% end %>
```

With the results of my debug above I would have thought my form would work just fine but it doesn't and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `title' for #<Parse::Object:0x007fff0fedd1e0>
```

What could the issue be? I've done some googling and looked at the server logs but can't seem to find what is wrong. As soon as I remove the form and just leave the debug line in the error is gone. So the error is definitely being caused my form.

**This is my model just incase you're wondering:**

```
class Garment
    include ActiveAttr::Model
    #include ActiveModel::Validations
    extend CarrierWave::Mount

    attribute :alternativeColour
    attribute :title
    attribute :image
    attribute :image2
    attribute :image3
    attribute :image4
    attribute :image5
    attribute :image6
    attribute :price
    attribute :recommended
    attribute :gender
    attribute :productType
    attribute :size
    attribute :colour 
    attribute :collection

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

Help will be much appreciate.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `<%= debug @garment["title"] %>`  You aren't calling a method here, you are calling the key for a hash.  Are you sure that's not your problem?  You're getting a hash back in your `garment` variable, not an object, and rails form_helpers are trying to call object methods. -- Or it may not be an actual hash, but it's an object that acts like one.  Does calling `@garment.title` work?  Or can you only get it with `@garment['title']`?

Comment: But this is how I call object properties from parse.com. Look here https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client there is no other way for me to read the object porperties.

Comment: The error is coming from the form. Even when I remove the debug code the error is still present.

Comment: At what point does a `Parse::Query` instantiate a `Garment` class?  Your error mentions `#<Parse::Object:0x007fff0fedd1e0>`, but not the actual `Garment` class you have defined, is that class being used?

Comment: @nzifnab I'm using a database from parse.com and not the one defined. Basically this is a tableless app. Not using Active Record.

Comment: I recognize you aren't using active_record, but that doesn't mean you're not still dealing with ruby classes and objects ;)  You can instantiate a garment class yourself if you want to use that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing my original answer... try changing your controller code to instantiate your garment class:

```
  def edit
      @garment = Garment.new Parse::Query.new("Garments").eq("objectId", params[:id]).get.first
  end
```

I looked at the active_attr code and it looks like this will work *if* that `Parse::Query` is returning a hash (which it seems like it is).

**Old Answer**

Try adding this to your `Garment` class definition:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  if self[method_name.to_s].present?
    self[method_name.to_s]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

You'll have to append to this to make setters work correctly.

This assumes that your `Parse::Query` call is at some point instantiating a `Garment` class. Where does that happen?

Comment: I thought that's what was happening in the edit action. After all I do get an object returned.

Comment: How do I use the code above. Do I paste in my model as is?

Comment: Well I don't know, your object dumps are saying they are `Parse::Object` classes, not `Garment` classes.  Do you need to name your class `Parse::Garment`?  Or instantiate it manually or something?    I'm not sure this code will work until you're actually dealing with a `Garment` class.  (For instance, if you call `Rails.logger.debug(@garment.class.to_s)` I suspect it won't say `Garment` or antying).

Comment: @LondonGuy I've updated my answer, try just instantiating the `Garment` class manually like I've mentioned and see if it then has access to things like `@garment.title`.  If that works, you don't need to add the method_missing that I had in here first.

Answer (score 0):

Change :garment to the actual object, ie

```
<%= form_for @garment, :url => adminpanel_url, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

Comment: `form_form @garment` and `form_for :garment` are *the exact same thing* if you have an instance variable named `@garment` available.  If you use the symbol, it looks for an instance variable of that name.

Comment: First thing I tried but gave me a undefined method model_name

Comment: @LondonGuy for that error you can add `extend ActiveModel::Naming` to your object's definition